# Laravel 5 error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, database, xampp, localhost, laravel-5

I have installed Laravel 5 successfully and changed MySQL credentials in database.php file in config directory to
    '

```
mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'wdcollect'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

I don't want to use homestead and I have changed .env file to

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=apLIzEMOgtc5BUxdT9WRLSvAoIIWO87N

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=wdcollect
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

I don't understand that why it's saying that access denied for 'homestead'@'localhost'

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for that user in mysql?

Comment: Personally I'd try connecting with those credentials on the command line using the `mysql` command. Then log in as root, verify that the user is authorized to connect to localhost, and reset the password of the user the application is using if neccasary

Comment: Creating a new user and assigning the user to the database helped in a hosting server. Also followed cache and config clear as suggested below

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's working now. I had to restart server. 
Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and fixed later automatically,I felt latest updates from laravel fixed the issue? did you feel that?

Comment: Just restart! and it comes back normal. OMG!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer.I met the same issue just now ,and restart the server,and it's working now!

Comment: This happened to me on a production server through https...working correctly through console.... rebooted, everything was better

Comment: Is It the apache server or the web server that you restarted?

Comment: I restarted PHP web server.

Comment: .I met the same issue just now ,and restart the server user *php artisan serve* ,and it's working now!

Comment: Same, I am using artisan to serve my laravel project, just stopped the ```serve``` and re-ran ```php artisan serve``` and it worked.

Answer (score 57):

I was facing the same issue. Everything was fine but in

> bootstrap/cache/config.php

always had the incomplete password. Upon digging further, realized that the password had '#' character in it and that was getting dropped. As '#' is used to mark a line as a comment.

Comment: You can also put  your password within ".

Comment: This was bang on target!. exactly I faced this issue while upgrading from Laravel 5.5 to 5.8. the same database credentials were not giving me permission.

Comment: You saved me with that '#' idea. I would never have though that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is bang on target indeed. I simply placed my password in config\database.php file and it worked.

Answer (score 36):

I spent hours on this :-( and finally, it was really easy to hack

**BEFORE**

```
DB_PASSWORD=#Root2020$
```

**UPDATED**

```
DB_PASSWORD="#Root2020$"
```

I think the problem was # in the password, that's why I had to write my password into quotation marks.

Comment: thank you, it solve in my case (laravel 8.35 in local dev), even if there are no special character !

Comment: Been there.. Done that 

Comment: Seems like the hash is causing this problem. S#####it!

Comment: many tanks; i can't believe i forget that...

Answer (score 33):

You need to run these two commands

```sh
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 22):

None of these worked for me when I deployed my website online on shared hosting, below is what I did that worked.

In the `.env` file, I changed

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

and viola, it worked well as expected.

Comment: in addition, you can check if the other data is correct, at least in my case, my password was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't guess it. It was working on previous server with 127.0.0.1 but it wasn't work with new server. So, with this answer I solved my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: works for me in Laravel 8 Environment, thumbs up

Answer (score 16):

if you before use localhost and root your file be cached

remove /bootstap/cache/config.php

Answer (score 11):

This works to me:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, so I realized that the `.env` file does not accept special characters, as my password has these characters, I added the password in the `config/database.php` file.

Comment: Thank you so much, i add double qoutes "my_password" and it's work fine!

Comment: Thank you this works for me too , I also added double quotes in my password in .env file , I am also using special characters in my password.

Answer (score 8):

Jeez!
Thanks to umair.ashfr answer here below, I finally hit the nail with an issue that was eating my neurons.

I had a password like
DB_PASSWORD=ffjdh5#fgr
on my .env, and MySQL connection was gracefully saying that "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user...", no matter what flavor of php artisan I was trying to run.

The problem was that "#" sign inside the password.
BEWARE! That means the start of a comment, thus my password was silently truncated!
The solution is to declare password like
DB_PASSWORD="ffjdh5#fgr"

Regards

Comment: Thanks. It's work for me. Problem in # sign. when i use # as db password in env it's shows that error. After set password without now it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I Faced Same Problem what i did

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:cache

but Same problem found than i run this artisan command

php artisan view:clear

Hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 5):

It happens when password contains special charecters
In that case we can put the password into string like

### DB_PASSWORD="your password"

In my case that works fine

Comment: Already explained in other answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/67857815/2227743

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using this

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=wdcollect
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

USE this

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=wdcollect
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

Comment: describe the answer what was the error how you solved.

Comment: The error was the user didn't get any permissions to access the database. We can resolve this error by assigning new user roles and permission by creating or editing a user in privileges section.

Answer (score 3):

Declare password like DB_PASSWORD="2o0@#5TGR1NG" in .env file

If # sign include in your password then password will declare in between " ".

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to set credentials in database.php file. It is enough if you have credentials in .env

If you are able to login to database directly then this password must work. It can be possible that you are having different environment than "local" which is defined in this file. Test is with "php artisan env"

Comment: current application environment: local

Comment: in L5 there is no such local/prod, theres one .env file that decides everything (it is git ignored so on production you dont rewrite it uppon git push)

Answer (score 2):

Try to checkout the ".env" file in your root directory. It will be a hidden file. Correct these values.

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=homestead
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: This worked for me, specially when i tried to change the values in database.php and I kept getting the error as if I didn´t change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Please update below file.

vendor - .env - on line#7

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=homestead
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Instead of homestead user your database, username and password. This should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MAMP

Check your port number as well generally it is

Host localhost

Port 8889

User root

Password root

Socket /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit the file .env in your laravel root directory. make looks as in below :

   ```
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_DATABASE=laravel
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=your-root-pas
   ```
2. Also create one database in phpmyadmin named, "laravel".
3. Run below commands :

   ```
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan config:clear   
    php artisan migrate
   ```

It worked for me, XAMPP with Apache and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

/bootstap/cache/ (remove the all cache files manually)

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was # in the password, that's why Laravel showing error, you had to write  password into quotation marks if you have special character in your password.

```
DB_PASSWORD=Test@123##   //not working without double quotes.

DB_PASSWORD="Test@123##" //working with double quotes.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. just run it in terminal

   php artisan optimize
2. then restart

   php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

Pls Update .env file

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=homestead
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

> After then restart server

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this too...
then I solve it by putting the database information directly in  " database.php " 
In your case, I would change the information like this

```
mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'wdcollect',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

and don't forget to change your setting in XAMPP's config.inc

```
['auth_type'] = 'config';
['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the .env file and the config.php file with your username and password and your hostname in the database settings.if they are not equal,relation will not connect.

Answer (score 0):

The .env file should have same database name , username and password as in the mysql database and check whether all permissions are granted to the user for accessing the database or not.
I solved my problem by adding the cpanel username in front of database name and username
like jumbo_admingo and jumbo_user1 respectively where jumbo is my cpanel username and admingo is the database name i created in mysql and user1 is the user which has been provided the access to the database admingo.
THIS SOLVED MY PROBLEM.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is the old database credentials are cached `/bootstap/cache/config.php`

In the .env file, I modified it as follow

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=homestead
 DB_USERNAME=homestead
 DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then removed that file

```
/bootstap/cache/config.php
```

**If the issue still there you might try the following.**

php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

Exit vagrant by writing the `exit` command
Then restart vargarnt/homestead config

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Then opened vagrant again

```
Vagrant Up
Vagrant ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal on XAMPP > go to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/project_name` > run `php artisan migrate`

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8080
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

[image: laravel: php artisan migrate on xampp terminal]

Answer (score 0):

in my case I wanted to connect to the database installed on windows that i used to access through workbench, so i replaced localhost with the ip address which i obtained by typing `ipconfig` on windows command prompt
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was actually root user permission problem. My `Laravel` configurations were all perfect, but later I found that it was root user permission problem since my MySQL configs were somehow changed.

- so i navigated to xampp folder > C:\xampp\mysql\bin
- searched for my.ini file and opened it in editor then added added `skip-grant-tables` in following place:

`[mysqld] skip-grant-tables port=3306`

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is.
Don't use specials character in db user password.
If you  really want to use special character then use double cote ""
After changing password in `.env` file you must have to remove `/bootstap/cache/config.php` **config.php** file or rename with others.

Answer (score 0):

Just have to delete next file:
bootstap/cache/config.php

Comment: Why do you have to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for you to follow would be to use the IP address directly.

For Unix like systems being MacOS:

In the terminal execute the command:

```
ifconfig | grep 192
```

or on Windows:

```
ipconfig | findstr "192"
```

With the result being something like:

```
inet 192.xxx.xx.xxx netmask......
```

Just put the ip address as your DB_HOST:

```
DB_HOST=192.168.68.152
```

This resolved it for me.