# MySQL+Laravel: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'so'@'localhost' but connection data is OK and config cache is cleared

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need help here, because it's driving me crazy. I'm trying to connect to the remote production DB but I'm unable. I have read tons of posts about this that are focusing on the credentials and also running the following commands to clean config that are stored in Laravel cache:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan config:clear
```

[Laravel 5 error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383141/2936486)

Any of these are working for me.

I have checked very well the credentials both in my .env file and my database.php. I'm able to connect to a local database by using the ip "127.0.0.1" but I'm unable with the production DB stored in Google Cloud. It's good to mention that my local IP is allowed to access that Database and I'm able to connect by using **MySql Workbench**.

Here is what I see when I perform "php artisan tinker" and then "DB::connection()->getPdo();" to check my connection from terminal:

[image]

The only thing that calls my attention is the message containing *"so@localhost"* when I'm not performing a connection to localhost but I don't know if that's related with the issue.

Any other suggestion? I have lost too much time trying to find out what could be happening.

EDIT 1: Laravel Framework 5.8.38

Comment: What is your `default` connection set ? `config('database.default')` ?

Comment: default is MySQL. I have declared at the begin of my database.php as following:      'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

Comment: What i may suggest for debugging (you may had done all) - try to change credentials one by one (+ `php artisan config:clear `) to see if any of them is changed ? Create another connection array (foobar) put these credentials and set your default connection foobar to see if it works ? search `localhost` in your ide/editor and replace every one of them with arbitrary strings to find which `localhost` is used while trying to open connection. clear config everytime during this step-by-step debugging to not face any unexpected situation.

Comment: I did it, but same result. I'm starting to think if it's something related to MySQL users allowed, but nothing seems wrong. The weird thing is that I was able to connect a few days ago, and I'm still able to do it with the Workbench with these credentials. I'm absolutely confused. I can't remember fighting with an issue like this so long.

Comment: Even you make all the changes one by one, your code still trying to connect `localhost` ? I don't think it is related to your database credentials - but something in the code. If you want install a fresh laravel project(within 5~10 minutes) put these credentials. to see if it is going to connect?

Comment: I have found a laravel+mysql template. I'm trying to connect on that project to check if there's something wrong with the other one.

Comment: @Ersoy, same result on the other one. After cleaning the cache/config and adding my credentials on .env and database.php, I have the same result: PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'so'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

Comment: you are all trying in the tinker right ? what about some dummy controller method to select `return User::first()` - i am out of ideas by the way :(

Comment: Yes, I'm using tinker to test the connection. I did something similar by tring to connect in AppServiceProvider.boot() method with same results :( . I'm about 6 hours fighting with this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The weird thing is that is connecting perfectly against localhost. The problem is mainly with remote databases.

Answer (score 0):

After two days fighting with this one, I readed tons of posts and a lot of unuseful solutions I have found my solution by looking at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKE1G4sinBM).

Basically, you must stop you XAMPP MySQL Server and open **C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini** and edit by adding the following command **"skip-grant-tables"** after the [mysqld] attribute. The result in this file might look this way:

```
# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
...
```

After that, I ran "php artisan tinker" and *DB::connection()->getPdo();* and everything was connected again, but it's good if you first clean your cache and config.